# Extracting html code with Java

Tags: java, html, extract

I downloaded my personal data from Facebook and thought I could do something fun with it. I'm trying to extract a specific group chat that I have.

The size of the file I'm using is at 18 kB so it's lots of html code inside  tags without any id's or anything that would help extracting data. The only difference between all my chats are that it's different people involved so that's what I started checking for.

I'm using Jsoup (http://jsoup.org/) to do this. The hierarchy of the document is sorted like this:

```
<div class="thread">
    <div class="message">
       <div class="message_header">
            <span class="user">user_name</span>
            <span class="meta"> date_when_said </span> 
       </div>
    </div>
       <p>user_said_something</p>
</div> //div class thread ends
<div class="thread"> //new group chat begins
```

I started with just counting how many times each person in the chat has said something.

```
for(int i = 0; i < doc.select("div[class=thread]").size(); i++){
   if (doc.select("div[class=thread]").get(i).ownText().equals(chat_name)) {
         int children = doc.select("div[class=thread]").get(i).children()
                .size();
         int traverse = 0;

         while (traverse <= children) {
         
            switch (doc.select("span[class=user]").get(traverse).ownText()) {
                    case user_one:
                wordSaid[0] += 1;
                break;
            case user_two:
                wordSaid[1] += 1;
                break;
             }
         }
      }
```

What I'm doing here is that I first go through all the different chats with the for-loop. I then check if that thread's text is equal to the chat I want to extract.
If it is then I start to iterate down in all the children of that thread.

As the children of one thread can contain up to 2000 children this is taking a long time.

I would be happy for any suggestions or comments on what I have done so I can improve this and make it scalable and maybe find a smarted way to solve my task.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the `<span class="user">user_name</span>` only happens before a user says something in the chat, you could:

- create a Map, the key being the user name and the value being the number of times the user said something.
- select all user entries `doc.select("span[class=user]")`

  - for each entry get the map entry that has that user name
  - if the entry exists, increment the value by one, else create the entry and initialize the value to one

The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to count the children and go through the whole XML file.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer! I will try definitely try this.